# what is the meaning of func.sum(TableName.count)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am converting some SQLAlchemy code to Django ORM (...I am new to SQLA).

I have a line that looks like:

```
db_session.query(func.sum(MyTable.count)).filter_by(...).scalar()
```

The intention seems to be to generate a simple count, but in examples I found online the more idiomatic way to do that would be:

```
db_session.query(func.count(MyTable.id))
```

...does the first line do something different to this, or it's just un-idiomatic?

I thought it might be summing aggregate counts, but there only seems to be the one table involved and no `group_by` so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func.sum` generates a `SUM` expression, which sums the values.

`func.count` generates a `COUNT` epxression, which counts the values.

If you have [1, 2, 3, 4], sum will produce 10, count will produce 4.